# Prove that the identity map is continuous

Tags: general-topology

Hello I have problems with exercise

Let $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ be given topologies on a set $X$. Prove that the identity map
$(X, \tau_1) → (X, \tau_2)$, $x   \longmapsto x$, is continuous if and only if $\tau_1$ is finer than $\tau_2$

My attempt:

$\Rightarrow{}$) We have the function is continuous then $\tau_1 \subseteq{\tau_2}$

$\therefore$ $\tau_1$ is finer than $\tau_2$

$\Leftarrow{}$) By hypothesis $\tau_1$ is finer than $\tau_2$  then $\tau_1 \subseteq{\tau_2}$.

Le the function defined by $(X, \tau_1) → (X, \tau_2)$, $x   \longmapsto x$

I don't know how to continue

Thanks

Comment: Let $i:(X,\tau_1)\to (X,\tau_2)$ be the identity map. By definition, $i$ is continuous iff for any open set $U$, $i^{-1}(U)$ is also open. What does this mean in terms of $i$, $\tau_1$, and $\tau_2$?

Comment: $(\Rightarrow)$ How $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$? You didn't even explain how do you get that; besides that it is false and it is not what it should arrive at ($\tau_1$ is finer than $\tau_2$ means $\tau_2 \subseteq \tau_1$).

$(\Leftarrow)$ Nope, you should not define any function. You need to *assume* that $\tau_2 \subseteq \tau_1$ and *prove* that $\operatorname{id}_X : (X,\tau_1) \to (X,\tau_2)$ is continuous. To start, you know the definition of continuity?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving the identity functions is continuous iff $\tau_1\supseteq\tau_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982974/proving-the-identity-functions-is-continuous-iff-tau-1-supseteq-tau-2)

Answer (score 1):

First, remember that a function is continuous if for all open sets $U \in \tau_2$and $f:X\mapsto X, f^{-1}(U)\in \tau_1 $.

Actually though, the identity is continuous if and only if $\tau_2 \subseteq \tau_1$.
This is because for all $U \in \tau_2$, they are, by hypothesis, also elements of $\tau_1$. This fills in our definition since $f^{-1}(U) = U\in \tau_1$.