# Is the function $id:X \rightarrow X$ always continuous?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $(Y,t_1)$ and $(Y,t_2)$ be 2 topological spaces and $id:(Y,t_1) \rightarrow (Y,t_2)$ the identity function, is $id$ always continuous?

---

$f=id$

trying to find some counter example, I confused myself,
if we take $Y=\{1,2,3\}$ $t_1=\{\emptyset, Y,\{2\}\}$ and $t_2=\{\emptyset, Y,\{1\}\}$

Then $f(\{2\})=\{2\} \notin t_2$ or $f(\{2\})=\emptyset$ ? and i have the same question for the inverse $f^{-1}(\{1\})=1 \notin t_1$ or $f^{-1}(\{1\})=\emptyset$?

if $f^{-1}(\{1\})=1 \notin t_1$ then clearly $id$ isn't continuous but if  $f^{-1}(\{1\})=\emptyset$ then $id$ is always continuous.

what its true?

Comment: Since the function you have to work with is $id$ why are you mentioning a separate $f$? Shouldn't your $f$ just be $id$ in which case $f(y)=y$ for all $y\in Y$.

Comment: The identity is only continuous if one topology is contained in the other (the inverse image of an open set must be open so $t_2$ must be contained in $t_1$.).

Comment: $\text{id}$ is continuous iff $t_2 \subseteq t_1$. For any set $A\subseteq Y$: $\text{id}^{-1}[A]=A$.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2982974/42969